# Hawai'ian Surname Inheritance During Act To Regulate Names?

Tags: names, polynesian-languages

So, I was wondering how family names were inherited during the Act to Regulate Names in Hawai'i. There's some conflicting info: some sources seem to say that the given name of the father of the person in question became their new family name. However, I need to know if this was passed down as in...

Example A:
Kunui Aka Kamealoha (Grandfather)
Change initiated
Albert Kalani Aka (Father)
Leonard Kanoena Kalani (Son)

or Example B:
Kunui Aka Kamealoha (Grandfather)
Change initiated
Albert Kalani Kunui (Father)
Leonard Kanoena Albert (Son)

or Example C:
Kunui Aka Kamealoha (Grandfather)
Change initiated
Albert Kalani Kunui (Father)
Leonard Kanoena Kunui (Son)

or some other way.

Comment: This was migrated to History from ELU (by me on recommendation of a History mod), so maybe it should be deleted here?

Comment: History is the only place that this is appropriate and unanswerable. Law is an alternative, except it will get closed since it doesn't ask that the law was, it asks what actual behavior was.

Comment: I can delete it if you can show me a link to the migrated location?

Comment: [History link](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/69221/31542). You should probably register your account, since it may cause some problems for you if you don't (for example, only registered users can delete their questions).